# How do I include webpack generated html in Spring Boot app under static

Tags: spring-boot, webpack

I am currently integrating webpack with gradle like this...

```
task webpack(type: Exec) {
   commandLine 'webpack'
}
task npm(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'npm install'
}
npm_install.dependsOn npm_cache_clean
webpack.dependsOn npm_install
build.dependsOn webpack
```

Webpack then creates the JS files and html files in the `src/main/resources/static`. The problem I am having is the first time gradle is run it must create the jar before webpack runs because I get a 404 on `localhost:8080`. Whereas, if I run it once (so the files are already created) it finds the old ones.

Is there a way to run this webpack before the src/main/resources folder is grabbed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the situation, `processResources.dependsOn webpack` instead of `build.dependsOn webpack`